# scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix.toarray given arrays with all 0's

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scipy, tfidfvectorizer

I am looking to use TfidfVectorizer and then convert csr matrix to array, but the array returned only contain 0's. Need to understand what's going on.

```
vector = TfidfVectorizer() # convert data to Matrix
x_feature_train = vector.fit_transform(X_train) # Fit our Train Data
x_test_feature_test = vector.transform(X_test) # Fit our Test Data
arr= x_feature_train.toarray()
print(arr[0][0])
```

Output

```
0.0
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'> [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: The output that you show indicates that the corners of the matrix contain zero.  That doesn't mean *all* the values in the matrix are zero.  Check the value of `x_feature_train.nnz`.

Answer (score 0):

The output is a sparse matrix meaning that it is a matrix that contains a lot of zeros.

There is a chance that all the values are at the center area of this large matrix thus when the printing statement only print out the head and tail of the matrix, it seemed like they are all zeros.

Another case might be that there is something wrong with the `X_train` data.
Without additional information, we won't be able to tell, thus, as @desertnaut recommended, posting a minimal reproducible example would be helpful.